# Firebase functions 2nd gen not deploying

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy my first '2nd gen' firebase function like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const { onValueUpdated, increment } = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const myFunc = onValueUpdated(
     {
       ref: "/my/ref/here",
       instance: "my-instance"
     },
     (event) => {
          return ....
     }
   );
```

Previously all I had to do to deploy was 'firebase deploy --only functions' but that gets me this error now:

*Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions/v2/database'
Require stack:

- /Users//Documents/firebase/functions/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js*

The new line I added import-wise is the second line found in the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?gen=2nd#node.js_2

I have tried 'npm install' in the functions folder which some people suggest, but that just gets me this:
*
found 45 vulnerabilities (10 low, 14 moderate, 21 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details*

As npm audit is not completely safe to run either (from what I gather) I don't know how to proceed.

For reference, my package.json looks as following:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.8.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Your [`firebase-functions` dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions) is out of date and does not support v2 Cloud Functions. You should update your dependency and try again. Additionally don't forget to export `myFunc` from your index file. Also delete the text `functions.config().firebase`, it doesn't do anything in the modern functions SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @samthecodingman! I have made progress, I can finally deploy again, but in the final process of creating the function I am now getting this error:

functions: HTTP Error: 503, The service is currently unavailable.
⚠  functions:  failed to create function projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/functions/function-name

Comment: "Failed to create function" normally means there's something wrong server side, you'll need to log into your Google Cloud Console and look for logs related to Cloud Functions and Cloud Run. If that's your latest issue, I'd maybe reach out to Firebase Support themselves as its something on their end that we (users on SO) don't have access to check.